# Proxy user for DDL

Tags: oracle

I'm experimenting with the proxy user feature of oracle.

My sample: *user_a* has **only object privileges** and *user_b* has **only system privileges**. *user_b* is allowed to log in as *user_a*. So DDL and DML are separated.

The docs says, that *user_b* as *user_a* only has user_a privileges. That would mean, he loses its own rights?

Which difference does the `CONNECT THROUGH WITH ROLE` clause? Because a role could only chosen, if the *user_a* already got the role.

The only solution that I know, are system privileges with `ANY` clause (and without proxying), but then *user_b* could change objects in all other users, but I don't want that.

How could this problem solved?

Comment: Could you, just for clarity, state your problem?  To prove user_b (when logged in as user_a) has only privs of user_a, try executing something that only user_b can run by itself.

Comment: user_b should have system privileges while logged in user_a. But user_a shouldn't have them.

Answer (score 1):

User_B will be the owner of the objects and user_A is the user of those objects, which is a good separation and guarantees that the objects can not be changed by the application. You would not want user_A to be able to change any structure.

Normally you want an application manager to be able to connect as user_B to make the changes needed for a new version or something like that. If this is the case, you want your admins to have the possibility to connect through their personal accounts to user_B to do the changes. Since user_B is the owner of the objects, user_B also has the rights to use them.

So the solution is to use an application manager user to do the ddl using the proxy user. That is way better than giving dba privileges or *ANY* privileges to an application manager.